# Time language not changing in kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, time, language-support

In regional setting language is Eng-US. But not working in displaying time.

[image]

Comment: The time is changing but the language does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that there are a few `LC_*` lines in `/etc/default/locale` which set respective locale category to something else but `en_US.UTF-8`. One way, if you want your system completely in English, is to edit that file, and remove those lines.

Comment: Thx... It worked.